# Postfix doesn't work after some time

Tags: postfix, centos7, dovecot

I'm trying to install a mail server on my CentOS 7. I install *postfix* along *dovecot*. I managed to make some configuration. When I tried the day before yesterday to test  my server via *telnet* like

`telnet IP.Add.re.ss smtp`

I got this response:

`Connected to IP.Add.re.ss.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.`

Today, if I try the same command:

`telnet IP.Add.re.ss smtp`

, I get

`telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out`.

If I try the command from localhost, it gets the same response like the day before yesterday.

Does anyone have idea what the problem is?

---

The output from

`iptebles -L -v` would be:

```
 
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25 state NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:587 state NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:465 state NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:25 state NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:587 state NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:465 state NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:110 state NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:995 state NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:110 state NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:995 state NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:143 state NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:993 state NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:143 state NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:993 state NEW
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall problem.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider See my edit. With all this being said, I don't understand why connection is timed out only today, not the day before, too? I did no change to firewall since.

Comment: Your server is not the only place where a firewall can be. Does you hoster have one in front of your server? Your local machine could be blocking outgoing connections on port 25, as well as your local ISP. Have you ran an external test for your mail server? Just google for "mail server test", you will find lots of services.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Problem doesn't reside on ISP (I contacted them), nor with other firewall. This is directly exposed to the internet. I try to set it up first, so no other firewall in between.

Comment: Have you checked if Postfix processes are still running? First check `smtpd` as it is directly responsible for listening to port 25, but also `master` is worth checking because it is the one who controls everybody else. What is in the log files (mail.error, daemon, syslog)?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I already stated that telnet calls from localhost are working well. So it is running. (I checked the ports too via netstat). Log files is syslog (I mean /var/log/messages).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't got that. Ok, did you try to monitor traffic with `tcpdump`, i.e. if packets from other systems to local port tcp/25 reach this system at all? This will at least dicriminate cases if that there is a problem on the host itself or somewhere on the network.

Comment: Your best approach is to get a `tcpdump` as suggested by @NikitaKipriyanov. Also, have you tried the other ports, like `telnet IP.Add.re.ss 587` ?

Comment: @Lester 587 port is working well. I have to check with `tcpdump`. I didn't use `tcpdump`, but I logged with iptables port 25 and got nothing on log files while on 587 I got logs. I'll try with `tcpdump`.

Comment: You see how @GeraldSchneider's comment makes sense now, right? Although, what is your tcp `deny` rule? `REJECT` or `DROP`?

Comment: @Lester `DROP`. I talked twice with my ISP. They don't block any port for my server. So the issue is from my firewall (which I doubt because I logged all packets coming on 25 and nothing was logged while 587 packets were logged) or postfix, or I don't know. I have to investigate a little bit deeper. The point is I have no idea why this problem is.